# Do I have to turn off animations on Android while running an Espresso tests?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Documentation saids that I have to turn off animations on Android while running an Espresso tests, but my mates saids its not necessary. Where's the truth?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you should turn them off, with animations you may get some false-positives occasionally

e.g. when after opening new `Activity` you will try to do some click, but `Activity` isn't clickable yet, beacuse it is animating (enter anim). other example is: some methods are desired to fire not immediatelly, but when app state is "idle" - showing infinite circle progressbar will prevent execution of these methods, espresso will wait forever for animation end

still even with animations Espresso will work, so its not mandatory to disable animations, but this is strongly suggested